# Heroku restarting with SIGTERM status 143

Tags: heroku, puppeteer, scraper

I have a scraper running on `Heroku`. It has been running for a while (+- 2 months) and it has days where it does great and reaches its 1,000 maximum and days during which it just magically restarts.

Does anyone know what the reason could be for such a restart? The scraper is showing no errors, the only thing I can find is the message below in the `Heroku` logs:

```
Feb 05 03:02:55 scraper heroku/web.1:  Cycling 
Feb 05 03:02:55 scraper heroku/web.1:  State changed from up to starting 
Feb 05 03:02:57 scraper heroku/web.1:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
Feb 05 03:02:57 scraper heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 143 
Feb 05 03:03:16 scraper heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `npm start`
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Cycling` bit of the log here is the interesting one.

[Heroku will restart dynos every 24h](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts), and this process is called "cycling". This is what you're seeing here.

Comment: I've looked up every time the cycle starts and it seems to be 24h + 30min from each other. Will be looking for alternatives. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, it won't be guaranteed to be 24h sharp. Note that you won't get any service provider that will give you full uptime. Building your app to handle restarts would be the right way to fix this.

Comment: Especially if you want to keep deploying it.